# Twitter Api: Autocomplete with friends

Tags: twitter, twitter-rest-api

I'm trying to implement a "search for username" feature using the Twitter Api. Specifically, I need autocomplete.
I've noticed that `/users/search/` doesn't work well, while looking for friends it keeps suggesting people that has nothing to do with me until i enter the full name.
I thought of loading the list of friends, but:

1. It only gives IDs. With the limitations of the number of requests, getting all the IDs and calling the API again to get the screen_names would consume it all
2. It gives chunks of 5000 users. Again, for people followin 100.000+ users it would not be usable.

Any suggestion?